# How to Get Data from a Power BI dataset into a Excel table, and change all Headers

Tags: excel, powerbi, dataset, flat-file

I was working on a way to **return a flat file table in Excel** that **query an existing dataset** in Power BI- **and rename all the headers on the fly**. The two first steps is explained here, but I can`t find any good way to rename the headers. Normally this can be done in Power query. If I change name of the header. Refresh will then replace the header according to what is in the OLAP cube.

Today Get Data in Excel can connect to the dataset - But it can only return the dataset as a PivotTable.

[image: PivotTable is the only option]

I found a YouTube video that showed me a work-around. Import and set up the PivotTable with dimensions from two tables. Then drill into the data with the double click. If Excel-pivot generate a new worksheet, this will contain a new Query on the OLAP cube, with a Connection and Command Text.

Next step is to replace the Command text with the query found in Power BI (web).
Goto the Data set - and pick the table (or any fields needed) - And copy the Query to clipboard.

[image: In Power Bi web version]

Next you can replace the Command text with this query. And **Whola** - the flat file contains the entire table.

[image: Command text replaced]

If anyone can find a nice way to rename headers on the fly (without use of VBA) it will be appreciated. Otherwise I hope this post can be used as a learning experience for someone.

Hopefully Microsoft will implement a Get Data from Power Bi **as table option** in Excel soon, also that can handle this via Power query where user can manipulate headers as well by use of some DAX expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using VBA to clean up all the headers in all my sheets connected to the Power Bi (OLAP cube). I then perform a call to RenameAllOLAPSheetHeaders before using the data on other steps. That does a small test if data has been refreshed by looking for the '[' in one cell, and then do refresh of all sheet is present. Here is my code:

```
Sub RenameHeaders(sh As String)
' Removes tablename and keeep fieldname between [] from Header row
co = 1
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sh)
Do Until .Cells(1, co) = ""
tmp = .Cells(1, co)
A = InStr(1, tmp, "[")
If A > 0 Then B = InStr(A, tmp, "]")
If B > A And A > 0 Then tmp = Mid(tmp, A + 1, B - A - 1)
.Cells(1, co) = tmp
co = co + 1
Loop
End With
End Sub
Sub RenameAllOLAPSheetHeaders()
TestVal = Worksheets("SAP-ordrer").Cells(1, 1)
If InStr(1, TestVal, "[") > 0 Then
    ' Then rename headers
    RenameHeaders ("SAP-ordrer")
    RenameHeaders ("SAP-Op-linjer")
    RenameHeaders ("ZIQ09")
    RenameHeaders ("CC-WS Responsible")
    RenameHeaders ("Project Responsibles")
End If
End Sub
```